# Getting the parent resource from the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I've got two objects (@stacks and @stories) with has_many relationships (through @anthologies). Stories can be viewed individually (/stories/1/) or as a collection in a Stack (/stacks/1/stories/1/).

```
map.resources :stories
map.resources :anthologies
map.resources :stacks, :has_many => :stories do |stack|
  stack.resources :stories
end
```

I've got this basic frame working I'm trying to identify the when a story is being rendered as part of a stack so that I can build some navigation between stories. I figure the easiest way to do this is to check the URL for the primary controller, but 1) I don't know how to do this, and 2) it seems very un-Railsy, like there should be a more direct way.

Still getting my head around some of the basics of Rails here -- any recommendations on how to achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined both nested and non-nested routes for `:stories`. When your StoriesController receives a request with these parameters:

```
/stacks/1/stories # nested form
```

or with these

```
/stories # non-nested form
```

The route will map to `{:controller => :stories, :action => :index }`. In the nested form, the params hash will include `:stack_id => 1`. In the non-nested form, it won't.

Comment: Thanks. I get this in concept, but I'm missing how I actually check if stack_id is set from the view? I'm still groping around rails, and I can't seem to find the right way to access the variable to check if it's set and return the value. Any pointers?

Comment: That depends on how you handle the controller action. Typically you would set an instance variable, like `@stack = Stack.find(params[:stack_id)`. You can conditionally set this, as in the `before_filter` example. In the view, you can test for the existence of the variable using `defined?`, e.g., <% if defined? @stack %>

Answer (score 1):

if you are accessing the child resource then the params will include the parent resource by default.

For example "/stacks/1/stories/2/" will have a params structure like this:

```
{:action => 'show', :controller => 'stories', :stack_id => 1, :id => 2 }
```

If you want to find the nested resource in the controller just look for the presence of the parent_id in the params hash e.g.:

```
before_filter :find_stack

protected
def find_stack
  if params[:stack_id]
     Stack.find(params[:stack_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Not quite. Should be `:id => 2`, not `:story_id => 2`

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. But I'm afraid I'm missing something far more remedial. How do I access this from the view?

Comment: @iamlemur - possibly a bit late to the party, but hopefully helpful for others - to access the result of `find_stack` from the view, also assign an instance variable - such as `@stack = Stack.find(params[:stack_id])`. You can then access `@stack` from the view.